# Qt Creator + .NET Framework

Tags: .net, qt, c++-cli, qt-creator, kinect

I want to start a project in Qt Creator and I need to use some of the .net libraries such as the Kinect for Windows SDK.

If this is possible, how should I proceed? Where can I find the libraries to include in my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator is a C++ IDE and it is independent from any library. So this is possible. first dowanload and install [Qt libraries for MSVC 2008 or 2010](http://qt-project.org/downloads). Then add this Qt version to your QtCreator and your IDE will know standard include directory for Windows SDK and other Windows development components. If you exposed a linkage error just add proper linkage option to you project file. for example in order to using COM objects you should add `LIBS += -lOle32`   to project file.

Comment: ..can you give some links to any documentations?